# How to deal with Educational Testing Service (ETS) inefficiency and awful post-exam service?

Tags: graduate-admissions, international-students, deadlines, language-exams, toefl

I took the TOEFL test more than three months ago (outside US). Well before my deadlines. But I haven't received the paper scores yet and I shall mail them to the admission committees as an obligatory in my application package. Now, I'm running against the clock. Although I contacted customer support at ETS, the only thing I got is copy-pasted information of mailing time (allow 4-6 weeks abroad...) with a we-can-do-nothing-else statement.

This is totally upsetting. I don't want to lose my applications (and the money I have spent to get all my document translated, legalized, etc.) because of such kafkian situation. Also, it doesn't make sense to order extra reports; probably, they will get lost again.

Has anybody else passed throughout this predicament with ETS? What did you do? What should I do?

Comment: Can you call them? Is there a twitter account? Tweet about it. And, contact the places that you applied to about the problem. Some may be able to give you extra time.

Comment: I called them, same answer. I don't have Twitter or Facebook (I suppose there isn't going to be too much difference to using e-mail). I contacted the administrators of the program I'm applying and they say that some extra time may be allotted, but sonner or later I have to show them the report. They don't have institutional code.

Comment: Don't stress. Telephone the admissions office and let them know the situation. They will likely allow you to send the TOEFL scores slightly late via fax or e-mail, with hardcopy to follow by postal mail.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem during my undergrad application process. The admission officer told me to fax them a print of my score report from my online account. You can try asking the admission office at the institute that you are applying to and see if there is any way you can self-report the score before the official report arrives. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a probable cause for the mail delay - weather.

I am a retiree from the US and I currently live in Taiwan. In the past month or so, I have experienced mail delays between the US and my current residency. Usually the first class air mail (US Postal Service) between the US and Taiwan is about 2 weeks ( sometimes 3 weeks at most). But, recently the time is about a month. And I haven't received couple of mails from US that were supposed to be delivered in the last week of December last year.

I mailed something to the US the week before X'mas. The receiving ends said they have not got it. I had to check with the local post office, their response was that this was due to the bad weather in December and January in the US.

My advice is: contact the admission offices to see if there is another way to send in the official transcript. Even if you receive the score report today, please consider using express mail to send to the universities because it could take another month or so for delivery. (I do know express delivery is expensive, bit it's worth it if you have good chance to get to a good university). Good luck!